# Unsolved Syntax Error in Bash Function

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, scripting, sh

I'm writing a script for a Raspberry Pi that I had working a few days ago, but now seems to have died once I added some additional code. I've attempted to resuscitate, but I'm coming up short. I am getting "Syntax error near unexpected token `done". I've researched it, but I'm not getting anywhere. dos2unix doesn't help (especially since I've coded the entirety of this on Debian 8.) and cat -v doesn't turn up anything. Offending module is as follows:

```
    24Monitor() {

        clear
echo "Beginning speed tests and traceroutes now. You can just... go do whatever it is you do."
        while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
                TestNum=$(($TestNum+1))
                echo "Speedtest Result #" $TestNum >> ~/speedtest.log
curl -s  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sive/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -
                cat ~/tmp.log | sed -e "s/^/$(date -R) /" >> ~/speedtest.log
                echo ""  >> ~/speedtest.log
                traceroute mayernetworks.com > ~/traceroutes.log
        done

        }
```

I would appreciate any and all insight, as I'm still growing in my scripting knowledge...

EDIT: Variable initilization by request:

```
end=$((SECONDS+86400))
```

Comment: Your first `echo` line: you start a string that does not terminate (you forgot the closing `"`). Suggestions: use an editor that understands shell script syntax, and/or shellcheck. There is also [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Actually, that was a quirk of my copying the code from nano. It truncated the line with a $ due to it not fitting in the terminal. See edited code.

Comment: Alright, where do you initialize `$SECONDS` and `$end` ? If one or the other is empty you might get surprises without quoting those

Comment: Added to original post. Also, $SECONDS is built into bash, as I understand it. I should point out that this portion of the code was working at one point.

Comment: (ah yes `$SECONDS` is builtin, right). By the way, make sure you're always running it with bash, as Posix sh does not support function names that start with a numeric character (if I were you I'd rename anyway). But that's probably not the issue. Hmmm. I can only imagine a parse error before that section :-/

Comment: You must quote URL after `curl`, because semicolon has another syntax meaning in shell script

Comment: Learn to use http://shellcheck.net to present code that at least is syntactically correct. Good luck.